# How to became superuser on AWS EC2 WordPress Site

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

I want to install SSL on AWS EC2 WordPress Site,

I have tried this:

```
bitnami@ip-172-24-0-191:/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs$ sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool
An updated version is available. Would you like to download it? You would need to run it manually later. [Y/n]: Y

The tool will exit now. To run the updated version run the following command: 

/opt/bitnami/bncert-tool 

bitnami@ip-172-24-0-191:/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs$ /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool
```

but I have this error:

```
Error: There has been an error.
This installer requires root privileges. Please become superuser before 
executing the installer
Press [Enter] to continue:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to log in with AWS root user first.

Installing SSL depends on your web panel like cpanel, cyberpanel, directadmin etc.

If you have bought a SSL then install it via panel first.

If you want to install SSL via SSH access, Be sure your SSH port is open and the credentials are correct.

Your error is showing because of not root user access.
Thanks.